# Magento 2 - Prevent form submit on page reload when Product add from sample script to Magento Shopping Cart

Tags: magento2, module, cart, event-observer

Below sample PHP script will list **simple/configurable** product with add to cart button. When user clicks on submit button, it will redirect to Magento shopping cart page and selected product will be shown in cart with quantity.

```
<form id="addproduct" name="addproduct" method="post" action="http://localhost/magento-2/checkout/cart/">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="prod_id[]" value="67" class="prod_chk" />Chaz Kangeroo Hoodie
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="prod_qty[]" disabled="disabled" class="prod_txt" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Color:
                <select name="prod_color[]" disabled="disabled" class="prod_clr">
                    <option value="Black">Black</option>
                    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                    <option value="Gray">Gray</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                Size:
                <select name="prod_size[]" disabled="disabled" class="prod_size">
                    <option value="S">S</option>
                    <option value="M">M</option>
                    <option value="L">L</option>
                    <option value="XL">XL</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="prod_id[]" value="1" class="prod_chk" />   Joust Duffle Bag
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="prod_qty[]" disabled="disabled" class="prod_txt" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index"> 
        <observer name="addproduct_display" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ThirdPartyAdd" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class ThirdPartyAdd implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, 
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, 
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, 
            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Submit') {
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_POST['prod_id']); $i++) {

                $qty = $_POST['prod_qty'][$i];

                $productModel = $this->_productFactory->create();
                $product = $productModel->load($_POST['prod_id'][$i]);

                $product_type = $product->getTypeID();

                if ($product_type == 'simple') {
                    $params = array(
                        'qty' => $_POST['prod_qty'][$i],
                    );
                    $this->_cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                    $this->_cart->save();
                } if($product_type == 'configurable') {
                    $simple_products = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product); 
                    $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);

                    foreach ($simple_products as $simple_product) {
                        $super_attributes = array();
                        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                            foreach ($attribute['values'] as $value) {

                                if ($value['label'] == $_POST['prod_size'][$i]) {
                                    $super_attributes[$attribute['attribute_id']] = $value['value_index'];
                                }
                                if ($value['label'] == $_POST['prod_color'][$i]) {
                                    $super_attributes[$attribute['attribute_id']] = $value['value_index'];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $this->_cart->addProduct($product, array(
                        'qty' => $_POST['prod_qty'][$i],
                        'super_attribute' => $super_attributes
                    ));
                    $this->_cart->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Issue - After product is added to cart, when user reloads the page, it
>   again submit the form and runs the script to add product. How do I
>   prevent form submit when user reloads/refresh the cart page ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your observer code like this.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class ThirdPartyAdd implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface 
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request) 
    {
       $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() != 'checkout_cart_index')   
      {
         // DO YOUR CODE HERE
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: The action equals to `checkout_cart_index`, so it does not go into the condition even. For the first time when prod is added and redirected to magento cart, it is adding the prod, but on next reload, it should not

Comment: have you still face any issue?

Comment: Yes, using the above snippet, I am unable to add product coz it equals to condition

Comment: can you tell me when you try to add product, which FullActionName() you get?

Comment: The action name I get is `checkout_cart_index`. Code flow change like this - `if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() != 'checkout_cart_index')   
      {
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Submit') {`

Comment: you get this when you try to add product to cart?

Comment: Yes, while trying to add prod, I get this action name, so it will not be equal in IF condition and thus prod wont be added if I use action name condition

Comment: Shall I change condition to something else ?

Comment: yes you can change condition.

Comment: Which condition should I change ? Could you update the answer with changed condition ?